# How to replace full column with the last value?

Tags: shell, csv, awk

I'm trying to take last value in third column of a CSV file and replace then the whole third column with this value.

I've been trying this:

```
var=$(tail -n 1 math_ready.csv | awk -F"," '{print $3}'); awk -F, '{$3="$var";}1' OFS=, math_ready.csv > math1.csv
```

But it's not working and I don't understand why...

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shell variable is not expandable internally in awk. You can do this instead:

```
awk -F, -v var="$var" '{ $3 = var } 1' OFS=, math_ready.csv > math1.cs
```

And you probably can simplify your code with this:

```
awk -F, 'NR == FNR { r = $3; next } { $3 = r } 1' OFS=, math_ready.csv math_ready.csv > math1.csv
```

Example input:

```
1,2,1
1,2,2
1,2,3
1,2,4
1,2,5
```

Output:

```
1,2,5
1,2,5
1,2,5
1,2,5
1,2,5
```

Comment: +1 for using an awk-only solution with some of the many little known features

Comment: Thanks! I'd prefer awk-only solution also. But could you please explain in more details what's the logic of it? I'm new for shell programming, sorry ;-)

Comment: @BorisKuryshev By passing `math_ready.csv` twice we make awk read it twice. The section `NR == FNR { r = $3; next }` targets the first loop. It reads the third column to `r` for every row. The last row would give the last value of `r`. `{ $3 = r } 1` processes the second loop. It replaces the third column with the value of `r` on every row. `1` is synonymous to `1 { print }` which always gives a true condition to process `{ print }`. `print` prints the current record.

Comment: To add more hint about how those two sections process the two sessions separately: in `NR == FNR { r = $3; next }`, `NR == FNR`'s only valid within the first since NR keeps incrementing even on the second session but FNR resets back to 0. This is why the condition is no longer valid on the next session. `next` makes `awk` jump to the next record without processing any statement that follows after it. Virtually this makes `{ r = $3 }` run only for the first loop and { `{ $3 = r } 1` run only for the second loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    BEGIN { ARGV[2]=ARGV[1]; ARGC++; FS=OFS="," }
    NR==FNR { last = $3; next }
    { $3 = last; print }
' math_ready.csv > math1.csv
```

The main problem with your script was trying to access a shell variable (`$var`) inside your awk script. Awk is not shell, it is a completely separate language/tool with it's own namespace and variables. You cannot directly access a shell variable in awk, just like you couldn't access it in C. To access the VALUE of a shell variable you'd do:

```
shellvar=27
awk -v awkvar="$shellvar" 'BEGIN{ print awkvar }'`
```

Some additional cleanup:

1. When FS and OFS have the same value, don't assign them each to that value separately, use `BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }` instead for clarity and maintainability.
2. Do not iniatailize variables AFTER the script that uses those variables unless you have a very specifc reason to do so. Use `awk -F... -v OFS=... 'script'` to init those variables to separate values, not `awk -F... 'script' OFS=...` as it's very unnatural to init variables in the code segment AFTER you've used them and variables inited in the args list at the end are not initialized when the BEGIN section is executed which can cause bugs.

Comment: I actually did this as `gawk BEGIN { FS = OFS = ","; ARGV[ARGC++] = ARGV[1] } ENDFILE { r = $3 } ...`. I just find that it complicates my answer.

Comment: Thats the way I used to do it too until someone proved to me that it's undefined behavior and so in some awks the `ARGC++` can be executed before the assignment. Since then I generally use `ARGV[ARGC] = ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++`.

Comment: Considered that but I also considered that mine only runs for gawk.

Comment: True, this is such a trivial solution though it doesn't seem worthwhile to make it gawk-specific as none of the gawk-only features make the script any simpler. Horses for courses, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one liner. It doesn't depend on the column count

```
var=`tail -1 sample.csv | perl -ne 'm/([^,]+)$/; print "$1";'`; cat sample.csv | while read line; do echo $line | perl -ne "s/[^,]*$/$var\n/; print $_;"; done


cat sample.csv
24,1,2,30,12
33,4,5,61,3333
66,7,8,91111,1
76,10,11,32,678
```

Out:

```
24,1,2,30,678
33,4,5,61,678
66,7,8,91111,678
76,10,11,32,678
```